# Importing user (Key (email)=() already exists)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-allauth

Im trying to import users from a cvs file. Some of the does not have an email, and this is causing some problem.

Im using Django 1.6 and the standard User.

This is the error I get, when trying to import a user without a email:

`IntegrityError('duplicate key value violates unique constraint "account_emailaddress_email_key"\nDETAIL: Key (email)=() already exists.\n',)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 437, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/<PROJECT>/apps/accounts/tasks.py", line 1151, in import_users_from_cvs
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 154, in get_or_create
    return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 391, in get_or_create
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 383, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1514, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 903, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<SITE>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "account_emailaddress_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
```

Here is db structure:

```
test_db=# \d+ account_emailaddress;
                                              Table "public.account_emailaddress"
  Column  |         Type          |                             Modifiers                             | Storage  | Description 
----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 id       | integer               | not null default nextval('account_emailaddress_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | 
 user_id  | integer               | not null                                                          | plain    | 
 email    | character varying(75) | not null                                                          | extended | 
 verified | boolean               | not null                                                          | plain    | 
 primary  | boolean               | not null                                                          | plain    | 
Indexes:
    "account_emailaddress_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "account_emailaddress_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
    "account_emailaddress_email_like" btree (email varchar_pattern_ops)
    "account_emailaddress_user_id" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "account_emailaddress_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "account_emailconfirmation" CONSTRAINT "account_emailconfirmation_email_address_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (email_address_id) REFERENCES account_emailaddress(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Has OIDs: no
```

Is there something I could do to fix this?

## Edit:

I could generate a random email address for each user without, but I still get an error

`IntegrityError('duplicate key value violates unique constraint "account_emailaddress_email_key"\nDETAIL: Key (email)=() already exists.\n',)`

Is there some way of "restarting" `account_emailaddress_email_key` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to use the standard Django auth.User to store these email addresses ([The email field of the standard django.contrib.auth.User is optional](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.email)).
You use a separated table to store users emails (account_emailaddress).

**When the processed user does not have an email address you should not try to add an email entry** (in this account_emailaddress table). Because of the unicity constraint on account_emailaddress.email column, Postgres sends you back an IntegrityError for the second empty email you try to create.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CustomUser class: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD

and then change the USERNAME_FIELD to the field that must be unique across users, in your case "email" is not one of them :)